# Relations orWhereDoesntHave dont work, how to fix?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

There is a relations "shop" with "setting_limits".
Need select all the products that fall under all the settings.
The store can set the sales settings, or it can not set, then you need to show all the products of this store.

```
 ->whereHas('shop', function ($query) {
                        $query->whereHas('setting_limits', function ($query) {
                            $query->where(function ($q) {
                                $q->where('type', '=' ,'sell_selected_countries')
                                    ->where('county_id', '=', 4);
                            })
                                ->orWhere(function ($q) {
                                    $q->where('type', '=' , 'sale_certain_countries')
                                        ->where('county_id', '!=', 4);
                                })
                                ->orWhere(function ($q) {
                                    $q->where('type',  '=' ,'sale_certain_areas')
                                        ->where('area_id', '!=', 5);
                                })
                                ->orWhere(function ($q) {
                                    $q->where('type', '=' , 'sell_selected_areas')
                                        ->where('area_id', '=', 5);
                                });
                        })->orWhereDoesntHave('setting_limits');
                    })
```

I tried this, it don't work, she does not see the products of the store that have no sales limit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my understanding shop has relationship setting_limits .So you can do somethink like below

```
->whereHas('shop.setting_limits', function ($query) {

            $query->where(function ($q) {
                $q->where('type', '=' ,'sell_selected_countries')
                    ->where('county_id', '=', 4);
            })->orWhere(function ($q) {
                    $q->where('type', '=' , 'sale_certain_countries')
                        ->where('county_id', '!=', 4);
                })->orWhere(function ($q) {
                    $q->where('type',  '=' ,'sale_certain_areas')
                        ->where('area_id', '!=', 5);
                })->orWhere(function ($q) {
                    $q->where('type', '=' , 'sell_selected_areas')
                        ->where('area_id', '=', 5);
                });
        })->orWhereDoesntHave('shop.setting_limits');
```

Comment: @РомаЛытарь can you show full code and is it setting_limits relationship in shop model

Comment: Sorry, it works as you wrote.
I have not relations whereHas to setting_limits

Comment: Thank you very much, I spent half a day